# Spring mvc replaces quotes with html symbol

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

However I try to get double quotes into my view spring somehow replaces them, here is what I've tried :

```
@RequestMapping(value="test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("test");
        Wrapper wp = new Wrapper();
        wp.setTestField("$(function() { alert(\"test\"); });");
        mav.addObject("testObject", wp);
        return mav;
    }
```

Wrapper is custom object with one field testField.

```
@RequestMapping(value="test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("test");
        mav.addObject("testObject", "$(function() { alert(\"test\"); });");
        return mav;
    }
```

And jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<c:out value="${requestScope.testObject.testField}"></c:out>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(&#039;test&#039;);    
</script>
```

I want to get :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("test");    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `<c:out>` automatically escapes your content.

To stop it doing that, use

```
<c:out escapeXml="false" value="${requestScope.testObject.testField}"/>
```

Comment: Or just use `<script type="text/javascript">${testObject.testField}</script>` when you're already on Servlet 2.4 / JSP 2.0 or newer (which is likely true for Spring MVC based webapps).

Comment: @BalusC: True, but my preference would be to make it explicit.